# Object Type in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object, graphql

I am running  a graphql mutation and depending on what the user inputs on the front end, I pass different variables in the graphql mutation using the `input` object.

```
const [updateUser] = useMutation<UpdateUserReponse>(UPDATE_USER);

  let submitForm = (
    email: string,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    newEmail: string,
    phoneNumber: string,
  ) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);

    if (email && (firstName || lastName || newEmail || phoneNumber)) {
      const input: any= {};
      if (firstName !== '') {
        input.firstName = firstName;
      }
      if (lastName !== '') {
        input.lastName = lastName;
      }
      if (newEmail !== '') {
        input.email = newEmail;
      }
      if (phoneNumber !== '') {
        input.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
      }
      updateUser({
        variables: {
          email: email,
          input: input,
        },
      })
```

However, I don't want to use `input: any` and want to be more specific. Generally, this is the input type that I am using in my mutation itself:

```
interface UpdateUserInput {
  email: String;
  firstName: String;
  lastName: String;
  phoneNumber: String;
}
```

I have tried using this instead of `any` but it doesn't work. I have also tried to use `object` but then I get errors like:

```
Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: Also, you can simply check if a value exists by doing `if (firstName) { stuff }`, no need to specifically use the !== operator since nonempty string value is truthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If depending on the input the data may exist or not, you can simply make them an optional property in the interface, that way you still get all the intellisense but if a property does not exist it won't throw an error.

So,

```
interface UpdateUserInput {
  email: String;
  firstName?: String;
  lastName?: String;
  phoneNumber?: String;
}
```